# Filter with a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(month_key = c(rep(201504, 2), rep(201505, 3)),
                 id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3))
```

I have a dataframe like df, for each month ID are not necessary distinct.
I want to filter my dataframe and keep only the ID with appears in the first month_key (in my exemple id = 1 and 2).
I don't want to select my id for the first month and inner_join with the other month ...
Thank you

Comment: ...I said il inner_join but its heavy i need something else

Comment: Consider providing another object containing your expected output.

Comment: You also need to know that downvotes represent the quality of your question. You did not include expected output, or any kind of code that you tried, hence the downvotes ( I did not downvote it).

Comment: But I cant show my data and I explain my method with the inner join and gave an example, thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ind <- df$id[df$month_key == df$month_key[1]]
df[df$id %in% ind,]
#  month_key id
#1    201504  1
#2    201504  2
#3    201505  1
#4    201505  2
```

Comment: Thank you my friend very nice ! if someone can give an dplyr solution it will be cool. Thanks

Comment: @user3 DF[cond, ] is roughly the same as DF %>% filter(cond), so `df %>% filter(id %in% id[ month_key == month_key[1]])` is the translation of this answer.

Comment: Thankss Frank for the solution

Comment: If the month key are not ordered, this solution works too ?

Comment: If I want the ID which appear on all my month_key what condition have I to add pls ?

Comment: @user3527451, if you want to obtain the id(s) appearing in all `month_key`, then, `Reduce(intersect, split(df$id, df$month_key))`

Comment: Thank you very much sotos it works !